# Return FeatureLayer in geoprocessing REST service

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-server, geoprocessing-service

I have created a Python Script Tool that returns a FeatureLayer using the following two lines of code:

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(scratch_fc, "GeocodedZIPsLayer")
arcpy.SetParameterAsText(1, "GeocodedZIPsLayer")
```

This works as expected in ArcMap, and resulting POINT features are added to the map without an issues.  When I publish this as a Geoprocessing Service, the service fails, and I see the following error in the server logs:

```
Invalid return value: GeocodedZIPsLayer
```

What is the best practice for returning a FeatureLayer through a REST service?

Comment: Have you tried just using [arcpy.SetParameter()](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/setparameter.htm) rather than returning it as text?

Comment: Try using copyfeatures instead of makefeaturelayer and just set the output to in_memory if that's your requirement

Comment: If I use CopyFeatures_management(), how do I return those features as an output parameter? What would I put in as the argument to arcpy.SetParameter(1,????)?

Comment: Also, the same error is returned when I use arcpy.SetParameter(1, "GeocodedZIPsLayer")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment - use CopyFeatures instead of MakeFeatureLayer

```
import arcpy
import os

# processing and analysis here...
myOutput = os.path.join(arcpy.env.scratchGDB, "output")
# ..or myOutput = "in_memory/output"
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(myInput, myOutput)

# use the output variable...
arcpy.SetParameterAsText(1, myOutput)
# ...or use the actual output
#  arcpy.SetParameterAsText(1,  os.path.join(arcpy.env.scratchGDB, "output"))
```

Comment: This solved the initial error, so I'll mark it as the solution.  Now debugging why my layer is empty...